# Java, return true if 'x' is next to 'y' in an array

Tags: java, arrays

This is, I imagine, a really simple problem to solve however I just can't figure it out.

An array contains a list of integers and I want to return true if every number 'x' in the array is followed by the number 'y'.

So arrays with `{x,3,4,y}` or `{x,x,y,4,5}` or `{5,8,x,x}` would be `false`.

Whereas arrays with `{x,y,4,1}` or `{x,y,5,1,x,y}` would be `true`.

This is what I have tried so far:

```
for (int i = 0; i < nums.length-1; i++)
{
    if (nums[i] == x && nums[i+1] == y)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

return false;
```

My code however will only work for the first two elements in the array (so 0 and 1). It won't detect any integers further down in the array, so how do I do this?

Thank you.

Comment: Actually, I don't see why it should return true on the second array based on your requiremet: the second 2 in the array is not followed by 2.

Comment: This code might throw ArrayIndexOutofBoundException if i points to last element and nums[i] = 2. There has to be bound check

Answer (score 5):

> I want to return true if every number 'x' in the array is followed by the number 'y'.

You need to get rid of the `else` and modify the checks like so:

```
for (int i = 0; i < nums.length - 1; i++)
{
    if (nums[i] == x && nums[i + 1] != y)
    {
        return false;
    }
}

return true;
```

Caveats:

1. This returns `true` if `x` is not present in the array. It's unclear from the question whether this is the behaviour you want.
2. This does not check whether `x` is the last element of the array. Again, it's not entirely clear what you'd expect to happen if it is.

Comment: That won't fix the algorithm: it would still return true at the first correct pair met, instead of checking that every x is followed by y.

Comment: @JBNizet: Good point. I missed that. The answer should be fixed now.

Comment: I want the statement to be true only if 'x' is followed by 'y'. I will update my question to help explain this and provide more examples.

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int i = 0; i < nums.length-1; i++) {    
    if (nums[i] == 2 && nums[i+1] != 3) {
        return false;
    }
}

return true;
```

Comment: you are Wrong may be?

Answer (score 1):

This code will return False iff the `'x'` number is not followed by `'y'`.

```
for (int i = 0; i < nums.length-1; i++)
{
    if(nums[i] == 2 && nums[i+1] != 3) {
        return false;
    }
}
return true;
```

Answer (score 1):

When the code reaches a `return` statement it stops executing the function and returns the specified value, that's why your for is only executed once.

Since you want the condition to apply to ALL the elements in the array, you have to return false when you find a 2 that isn't followed by a 3. If the 2 is followed by a 3, you just keep checking the next position.

Like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < nums.length-1; i++)
{ 
     if(nums[i] == 2 && nums[i+1] != 3)
     {
          return false;
     }
}
return true;
```

Comment: Finally, some code that is almost correct (it doesn't jump over y when a pair is found, as it should based on the OP description)

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 0; i < nums.length-1; i++)
  {
    if(nums[i] == 2 && nums[i+1] == 3)
    {
    return true;
    }

  }
  return false;
```

Comment: This code might throw ArrayIndexOutofBoundException if i points to last element and nums[i] = 2. There has to be bound check

Comment: I am not sure HOW?, because `i < nums.lenght-1` in the loop condition

Answer (score 0):

Your Code is returning in the first iteration always. because you have return written there in both If and else block.

remove the else case or just the `return;` from else case if there is any other logic inside.

```
int x = 2;
int y=3;
    for (int i = 0; i < nums.length-1; i++) {    
        if (nums[i] == x && nums[i+1] != y) {
            return false;
        }
    }
return true;
```

If you do not have x in the array, it will return true. and if you have any x that does not have y after it, it will return false.

Answer (score 0):

Try out Following

```
    boolean flag = false;
      for (int i = 0; i <= (nums.length-1); i++) {
         if(nums[i] == x) {
              if (i == (nums.length-1)) {
                  if(nums[i] == x) {
                      flag = false;
                  }
              } else {
                  if(nums[i+1] == y) {
                      flag = true;
                  } else {
                      flag = false;
                      break;
                  }
              }
           }
      }
      return flag;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it didn't work. Also in the for loop the array length must be -1.

Comment: can you tell me which condition failed. To execute loop till second last element in array it can iterated till (nums.length-1). Updated Answer for that.

Comment: Using your code it returns `true` on the following arrays `{5, X, Y, X}` & `{X, Y, X}` when they should be `false` and returns `false` on `{1, X, Y, 2, 4}` and `{X, Y, 2}` when they should be `true`. However it does return true on `{X, Y}` which is correct.

Answer (score 0):

You can try out the following:

```
if(nums[nums.length - 1] == x)
  {
  return false;
  }
else
  {
  boolean flag = false;

  for(i = 0; i < nums.length - 1; i++)
    {
    if(nums[i] == x)
      {
      if(nums[i + 1] == y)
        {
        flag = true;
        }
      else
        {
        flag = false;
        break;
        }
      }
    }

  return flag;
  }
```